# How many lines of code have been committed to my SVN repository?

Tags: svn, scripting, repository, unfuddle

How could I check how many lines of code have been committed to my SVN repository across all commits?

Comment: You mean all lines in commited file, or lines changed in commited file?

Comment: you might try http://www.statsvn.org/, it's not perfect, but it will show you roughly what you want

Comment: All lines in the most up to date committed files.

Comment: thanks, statsvn does give me basically what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use statsvn.org, what you need to do is get the files that was modified in the last N minutes and then run `wc -l`, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

LINES=0
SVNROOT=/path/to/svn/repo
MMIN=-5

for f in `find $SVNROOT -type f -mmin $MMIN`; do
    FILE_LINES=$(cat $f | wc -l)
    LINES=$((LINES + FILE_LINES))
done

echo "LINES COMMITTED IN THE LAST $MMIN MINUTES: $LINES"
```